I need to use an LC filter for voltage supply to a power meter. Do I need the same filters for the current input to prevent from the phase shift?
I have three single phase power meters which have issues with the common mode or differential mode (under investigation.) If I use a filter (LC type of some arrangements like T or PI) which will be connected just before the voltage input to the power meter will this filter change the phase and distort the power readings/power factor? If yes, should I use exactly the same filters on the current inputs (from CTs) which will introduce the same shift which in result be the same as on voltage line which will give accurate power readings?
Does a current transformer not change the phase of the current already before it is fed to the power meter? I believe normal transformers do that shift so CTs should not be an exception, I would imagine.

If the power meter directly multiples the V times the current, then you don't need to match the filters -- basically the power in (before the filter) is the same as the power out (after the filter) since the filter doesn't dissipate any power.
But, if you are just measuring rms V and rems I and then multiplying, the result will be incorrect (because of the phase shift). In that case, you'd need match the filters.
A CT (with sufficient bandwidth) will not have an appreciable phase shift.
